# Concurrent collections and unique elements

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing, blockingcollection, concurrent-collections

I have a concurrent `BlockingCollection` with repeated elements. How can modify it to add or get distinct elements?

Comment: Adding distinct elements appears to be [surprisingly hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603969/how-to-access-the-underlying-default-concurrent-queue-of-a-blocking-collection) if not impossible. `BlockingCollection` does implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can use `Distinct()`.

Comment: You could use the code provided in the StackOverflow question linked by GertArnold but simply always return true in the TryAdd and TryTake implementation of an IProducerConsumerCollection. This would work. I know it's terrible form but it _would_ work, and the BlockingCollection is already breaking form in that it throws an exception. How terribly annoying.

Answer (score 6):

The default backing store for `BlockingCollection` is a `ConcurrentQueue`. As somebody else pointed out, it's rather difficult to add distinct items using that.

However, you could create your own collection type that implements `IProducerConsumerCollection`, and pass that to the `BlockingCollection` constructor.

Imagine a `ConcurrentDictionary` that contains the keys of the items that are currently in the queue. To add an item, you call `TryAdd` on the dictionary first, and if the item isn't in the dictionary you add it, and also add it to the queue. `Take` (and `TryTake`) get the next item from the queue, remove it from the dictionary, and return.

I'd prefer if there was a concurrent `HashTable`, but since there isn't one, you'll have to do with `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of a [`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.iproducerconsumercollection-1) collection with the behavior of a queue, that also rejects duplicate items:

```
public class ConcurrentQueueNoDuplicates<T> : IProducerConsumerCollection<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> _queue = new();
    private readonly HashSet<T> _set;
    private object Locker => _queue;

    public ConcurrentQueueNoDuplicates(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default)
    {
        _set = new(comparer);
    }

    public bool TryAdd(T item)
    {
        lock (Locker)
        {
            if (!_set.Add(item))
                throw new DuplicateKeyException();
            _queue.Enqueue(item); return true;
        }
    }

    public bool TryTake(out T item)
    {
        lock (Locker)
        {
            if (_queue.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            item = _queue.Dequeue();
            bool removed = _set.Remove(item);
            Debug.Assert(removed);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public int Count { get { lock (Locker) return _queue.Count; } }
    public bool IsSynchronized => false;
    public object SyncRoot => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public T[] ToArray() { lock (Locker) return _queue.ToArray(); }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => ToArray().AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int index) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}

public class DuplicateKeyException : InvalidOperationException { }
```

Usage example:

```
BlockingCollection<Item> queue = new(new ConcurrentQueueNoDuplicates<Item>());

//...

try { queue.Add(item); }
catch (DuplicateKeyException) { Console.WriteLine($"The {item} was rejected."); }
```

**Caution:** Calling `queue.TryAdd(item);` is not having the expected behavior of returning `false` if the item is a duplicate. Any attempt to add a duplicate item results invariably in a `DuplicateKeyException`. Do not attempt to "fix" the above `ConcurrentQueueNoDuplicates<T>.TryAdd` implementation, or the `TryTake`, by returning `false`. The [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) will react by throwing a different exception (`InvalidOperationException`), and on top of that its internal state will become corrupted. There is currently (.NET 7) [a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/69816) that reduces by one the effective capacity of a `BlockingCollection<T>` whose underlying storage has a `TryAdd` implementation that returns `false`. The bug [has been fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/77936) for .NET 8, which will prevent the corruption, but it won't change the error-throwing behavior.