# How to wrap ConcurrentDictionary in BlockingCollection?

Tags: c#, concurrency, producer-consumer, concurrentdictionary, blockingcollection

I try to implement a `ConcurrentDictionary` by wrapping it in a `BlockingCollection` but did not seem to be successful.

I understand that one variable declarations work with `BlockingCollection` such as `ConcurrentBag<T>`, `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, etc.

So, to create a `ConcurrentBag` wrapped in a `BlockingCollection` I would declare and instantiate like this:

```
BlockingCollection<int> bag = new BlockingCollection<int>(new ConcurrentBag<int>());
```

But how to do it for `ConcurrentDictionary`? I need the blocking functionality of the `BlockingCollection` on both the producer and consumer side.

Comment: Dictionary (and ConcurrentDictionary too) doesn't preserve order of items. Can you describe your producer-consumer scenario?

Comment: @Dennis, I am aware of that. A producer stores KeyValuePairs in the concurrentDictionary, and a consumer task increments an int and removes the KeyValuePair if the int matches with the respective key. I do this because worker tasks populate the concurrentDictionary with values but in arbitrary order, the consumer task ensures received values are passed on/worked on in the right order. Can a ConcurrentDictionary be wrapped in a BlockingCollection?

Comment: What solution did you come up with?  I'm trying to find a good solution to a similar problem where the producer doesn't produce items in the order needed by the consumer. (old post I know, but it's worth a try)

Comment: Related: [Concurrent collections and unique elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652669/concurrent-collections-and-unique-elements).

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you need a concurrent dictionary of blockingCollection

```
        ConcurrentDictionary<int, BlockingCollection<string>> mailBoxes = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, BlockingCollection<string>>();
        int maxBoxes = 5;

        CancellationTokenSource cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken cancelationToken = cancelationTokenSource.Token;

        Random rnd = new Random();
        // Producer
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int index = rnd.Next(0, maxBoxes);
                // put the letter in the mailbox 'index'
                var box = mailBoxes.GetOrAdd(index, new BlockingCollection<string>());
                box.Add("some message " + index, cancelationToken);
                Console.WriteLine("Produced a letter to put in box " + index);

                // Wait simulating a heavy production item.
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });

        // Consumer 1
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int index = rnd.Next(0, maxBoxes);
                // get the letter in the mailbox 'index'
                var box = mailBoxes.GetOrAdd(index, new BlockingCollection<string>());
                var message = box.Take(cancelationToken);
                Console.WriteLine("Consumed 1: " + message);

                // consume a item cost less than produce it:
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        });

        // Consumer 2
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int index = rnd.Next(0, maxBoxes);
                // get the letter in the mailbox 'index'
                var box = mailBoxes.GetOrAdd(index, new BlockingCollection<string>());
                var message = box.Take(cancelationToken);
                Console.WriteLine("Consumed 2: " + message);

                // consume a item cost less than produce it:
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
        cancelationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

By this way, a consumer which is expecting something in the mailbox 5, will wait until the productor puts a letter in the mailbox 5.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write your own adapter class - something like:

```
public class ConcurrentDictionaryWrapper<TKey,TValue>
    : IProducerConsumerCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary;

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return dictionary.Count; }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get { return this; }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool TryAdd(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return dictionary.TryAdd(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public bool TryTake(out KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        item = dictionary.FirstOrDefault();
        TValue value;
        return dictionary.TryRemove(item.Key, out value);
    }

    public KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] ToArray()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code suggestion. But my main purpose in using a BlockingCollection was the ability to mark the collection as Adding Completed and to check for the status of it as well as whether its adding complete and empty, similar to what a BlockingCollection provides. I am aware I can easily add such functionality, but I am looking for a suggestion how to do it directly through the BlockingCollection. So far I do not see a reason why it can't work through the Blocking collection directly. Maybe it only takes  IProducerConsumerCollection<T>?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of a [`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.iproducerconsumercollection-1) collection which is backed by a [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2). The `T` of the collection is of type `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. It is very similar to [Nick Jones's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10738308/11178549) implementation, with some improvements:

```
public class ConcurrentDictionaryProducerConsumer<TKey, TValue>
    : IProducerConsumerCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;
    private readonly ThreadLocal<IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>> _enumerator;

    public ConcurrentDictionaryProducerConsumer(
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = default)
    {
        _dictionary = new(comparer);
        _enumerator = new(() => _dictionary.GetEnumerator());
    }

    public bool TryAdd(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> entry)
    {
        if (!_dictionary.TryAdd(entry.Key, entry.Value))
            throw new DuplicateKeyException();
        return true;
    }

    public bool TryTake(out KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> entry)
    {
        // Get a cached enumerator that is used only by the current thread.
        IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> enumerator = _enumerator.Value;
        while (true)
        {
            enumerator.Reset();
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            entry = enumerator.Current;
            if (!_dictionary.TryRemove(entry)) continue;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public int Count => _dictionary.Count;
    public bool IsSynchronized => false;
    public object SyncRoot => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] ToArray() => _dictionary.ToArray();
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
        => _dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int index)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}

public class DuplicateKeyException : InvalidOperationException { }
```

Usage example:

```
BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<string, Item>> collection
    = new(new ConcurrentDictionaryProducerConsumer<string, Item>());

//...

try { collection.Add(KeyValuePair.Create(key, item)); }
catch (DuplicateKeyException) { Console.WriteLine($"The {key} was rejected."); }
```

The `collection.TryTake` method removes a [practically random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75226870/is-concurrentdictionary-always-add-item-by-thread-order-in-c/75227410#75227410) key from the `ConcurrentDictionary`, which is unlikely to be a desirable behavior. Also the performance is not great, and the memory allocations are significant. For these reasons I don't recommend enthusiastically to use the above implementation. I would suggest instead to take a look at the `ConcurrentQueueNoDuplicates<T>` that I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652669/concurrent-collections-and-unique-elements/75354636#75354636), which has a proper queue behavior.

**Caution:** Calling `collection.TryAdd(item);` is not having the expected behavior of returning `false` if the key exists. Any attempt to add a duplicate key results invariably in a `DuplicateKeyException`. For an explanation look at the aforementioned [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652669/concurrent-collections-and-unique-elements/75354636#75354636).