# Loop through BlockingCollection<T> without consuming

Tags: c#, concurrency, blockingcollection

On the producer side of my program, while processing the items which will be sent to the collection, they must be checked whether a duplicate one is in the queue, so I need to loop through the `BlockingCollection<ConcurrentQueue<Message>>` at first place. But I could't find out how to loop through a blocking collection.

```
public BlockingCollection<ConcurrentQueue<Message>> Collection { get; set; } 
= new BlockingCollection<ConcurrentQueue<Message>>();

foreach(var item in Collection)
{
    //item is ConcurrentQueue<Message>
}

foreach (ConcurrentQueue<Message> queue in Collection)
{
    foreach (var item in queue)    
    {   
        //I don't know if it is efficient but I can reach like that
    }
}  

foreach(var item in Collection.Queue)
{
    // Is there an api something like that?
}
```

Comment: This is not impossible, but It tries very hard to discourage you from doing this.  Because it is fundamentally thread-unsafe, you cannot iterate a collection reliably when other threads are busy modifying it.  The guarantee that you won't add the same item twice is already pretty worthless, given that a consuming thread can easily remove the item a nanosecond before you check.  And you can't know that it is busy working on the item.  This won't happen nearly often enough to ever have a shot at debugging such a flaw.  Rather best to review the need for this, it is very smelly.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, adviced posts shows some try eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24073395/2289430 The facts you wrote are related with the implementation like that, right? And I want to be sure that I will never ever be safe with these implementations under high concurrency :)